# (Django/Javascript/SQLite3): How does this "class*=" selector work? What does it do

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, sqlite

I'm taking up a web dev project in Django that uses a database of greek and latin texts. This was worked on by multiple people, however I am taking up the project. I have introductory experience in Django and Javascript though, and while I've been able to learn a lot of new things I still have questions like this.

So take a look at these lines of code in our main.js file.

```
// Hide all text/book elements NOT part of the selected language:
books.not("[class*='" + lang + "']").css("display", "none");
// Show all which are part of the selected language:
books.filter("[class*='" + lang + "']").css("display", "block");
//What if I had a function that took books as an arg, and then app
```

In truth, I just do not know what syntactically is happening with the term,
`"[class*=]"`. However, I have learned what the .filter() and .not() methods do, as well as the .css() method.

However, these two lines of code seem to accomplish something important. They are able to determine which book objects are in the language that the `lang` variable (which is a string) specifies. `display:none` and `display:block` are applied when necessary.

I just can't find any documentation on what this selector is exactly or how it works. Also all of my coworkers who aren't as familiar with javascript are immediately thrown off by the fact that this selector uses the term "class." They think that would be referring to an html element that has a class that is equal to the string specified by lang (i.e. class="greek"). But there is no "greek" class.

My only guess is that this syntax allows us to access the database and check to see which records (or books objects) have a field or column that is set to "lang." This would be a useful selector for being able to have Javascript query my database for other things like book type, date, etc... So I need to know what's going on. Any slight explanation would be helpful. If you have links to documentation no matter how basic, if you feel it would help me get a better footing in Javascript and Django, please send it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a [css selector](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#selectors), in this case an attribute selector that looks for an attribute named class that contains a substring of greek.

> https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#selectors
>
> E[foo*="bar"] an E element whose "foo" attribute value contains the
>   substring "bar"

So with the code you show when the lang is passed the `.not()` line hides any element that does not contain `greek`. And the next line shows all elements that do have `greek` in it.

And it doesn't matter if there currently is no element with `class=greek` the code is meant to be dynamic. Meaning instead of hard coding for instance greek you can just pass greek in lang and only that would be shown. Or if say you change it to UK, only UK elements would be shown without needing to change the actual js code.

Comment: To be honest I am a little confused about the last two sentences because if you mean "pass greek in lang," well... lang is a string variable so I understand I could pass a string called "greek" or "latin" into it.

Comment: Lang is something that is declared based on when someone clicks a button entitled either greek or latin. I don't want to bug you with asking about javascript syntax but here it is.

Comment: ex: when someone clicks the latin button:

`$("#latin").on("click", {
            language: "latin"
        }, configureForm);`

`function configureForm(e) {
    var lang = e.data.language;
.... }`

I've always been a little confused about e.data but... I think I understand what's happening and have explained it to others.

Comment: @ByronSmith, that is what I meant by pass greek in, use greek or whatever as the string for lang. As for the last thing you mention, that is a jQuery thing, the second argument you are passing in is put into the `data` property. Have a [look at the api](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation